# JS (jQuery) script in view do not operate after AJAX request is sent to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

There is jQuery script in view. Script operates OK when the page is opened first time and data is put from server for view without AJAX. When I choose item from drop-down list, AJAX send it to controller. Controller render *.js.erb view and *.html.erb view shows info correctly for the last time. Since now it looks like script disappear from the view (from the page). No any reaction on choosing of the item from drop-down list.

But if I copy this script from *.html.erb view to *.js.erb view, everithing operates OK always.
I can not understand this behaviour. With AJAX I only change info in one div in view and do not touch script section of this view...

Action in values_controller.rb

```
@values = Value.all

# This value initially generates here and next time goes from view with AJAX
@chosen_value = if params[:chosen_value].present?
              Value.find_by(label: params[:chosen_value])
            else
              'Just_label_of_my_value'
            end

respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html { render 'value_shows' }
end
```

value_shows.html.erb

```
<div id="graphs">
  <div>
    <%= select("label", "label_value", @values.collect { |c| [ c[:name], c[:name] ] }, { prompt: '[Choose label]'}) %>
  </div>

  <%= @chosen_value %>
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    if (!$('#label_label_value').val()) {
      $('#label_label_value').val('<%= @chosen_value %>')
    }

    $("#label_label_value").change(function() { 
      $.ajax({ url: "/value_action", data: { 'chosen_value' : $('#label_label_value').val() }});
    });
  });
</script>
```

value_shows.js.erb

```
$("#graphs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'graphics') %>");

// If I copy script from view to here, everithing operates ok:
$(function(){
  if (!$('#label_label_value').val()) {
    $('#label_label_value').val('<%= @chosen_value %>')
  }

  $("#label_label_value").change(function() { 
    $.ajax({ url: "/value_shows", data: { 'chosen_value' : $('#label_label_value').val() }});
  });
});
```

_graphics.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= select("label", "label_value", @values.collect { |c| [ c[:name], c[:name] ] }, { prompt: '[Choose label]'}) %>
</div>

<%= @chosen_value %>
```

### Update

1. Sorry I incorrectly paste code of view and partial:
   drop-down list is **inside** div which is updated by partial.
2. I put the drop-down list out from the updated div and everithing begin to operate correctly every time. This way opeartes OK constantly:

value_shows.html.erb

```
  <div>
    <%= select("label", "label_value", @values.collect { |c| [ c[:name], c[:name] ] }, { prompt: '[Choose label]'}) %>
  </div>


<div id="graphs">
  <%= @chosen_value %>
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    if (!$('#label_label_value').val()) {
      $('#label_label_value').val('<%= @chosen_value %>')
    }

    $("#label_label_value").change(function() { 
      $.ajax({ url: "/value_action", data: { 'chosen_value' : $('#label_label_value').val() }});
    });
  });
</script>
```

value_shows.js.erb

```
$("#graphs").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'graphics') %>");
```

_graphics.html.erb

```
<%= @chosen_value %>
```

### Questions

1. As I understand, after partial replaces div content bunding lost. Why does it happen? Names and ids of elements inside div remain the same.
2. It is required that drop-down list should be inside updated div. I replaces this script:

```
$("#label_label_value").change(function() { 
      $.ajax({ url: "/value_action", data: { 'chosen_value' : $('#label_label_value').val() }});
    });
```

with this:

```
 $("#graphs").on("change", "#label_label_value", function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "/value_action", data: { 'chosen_value' : $('#label_label_value').val() }});
  });
```

and AJAX request now operates OK everytime.
So please advice if is it possible to change the first part of the script in the same way?

```
if (!$('#label_label_value').val()) {
  $('#label_label_value').val('<%= @chosen_value %>')
}
```

Find only one working way: add first part of script to *.js partial. Because rails value from controller could be catched only here:

```
if (!$('#label_label_value').val()) {
  $('#label_label_value').val('<%= @chosen_value %>')
}
```

Comment: where do you specify what should happen when the response is received to the ajax request? Am I missing it?

Comment: @LesNightingill, thank you for you question. I did not specify what should happen because it must be done only with Rails' controller and view. JS only must send label to controller and not more. Maybe I wrong... Describe logic more deeply: in reality controller creats set of data for gem 'apexcharts' and in view chart is shown on the basis of label which is chosen in drop-down list. But if I remove all chart logic and only show recieved value from controller  - everithing operates as I describe: only one time after itme is chosen from drop-down list.